# Python '_AppCtxGlobals': Attribute Error in Flask

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I have implemented a code to calculate api time.

```
@api.app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.request_start_time = time.time()

@api.app.after_request
def after_request():
    elapsed = time.time() - g.request_start_time ------> Error here.
```

I am having error for ~1-2% api calls.

Error:

```
'_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'request_start_time'
```

I am not able to debug this. This can only happen if :

1. the api does not pass through before_request function.
2. the global context get reset in between the code.

First seems not to be happen as every api request should pass the before_request function.
I am not able to find when the second case can occur. What are the scenarios when the global context get reset in between call.

Is there anything I am missing here ?

EDIT:

I have been observing the cases when this error is occurring and found the similarity that all calls were having `400 BAD REQUEST`. But I am still not able to get the root cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and  is due because you called a variable `g`, so flask confuse it with the global application context also called `g`.

Have a look here:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.ctx._AppCtxGlobals

```
Creating an app context automatically creates this object, which is made available as the g proxy.
```

So try renaming your **g** variable in `g.request_start_time = time.time()`that you probably inherit from somewhere else.

If you are referring the flask context and having error correlated to 404 requests, it might be that when you call after_request() it does not find any attribute `g.request_start_time` , maybe because if requests fail the attribute is not created.